# Problem with saving php sessions in different directory

Tags: php, session, ovh

I'm trying really hard to save my sessions in different directory. 
I have a shared server in OVH. Default session save path is `/tmp`, and I want to change it.

In my root directory I have `www` folder which is my main website folder. I created 'sessions' folder next to it, chmoded 777. 
When I'm doing `print_r(scandir('/home/expressptp/sessions/'));` i'm getting files just fine, but when I try to `session_save_path('/home/expressptp/sessions');` nothing ever appears there.

Full code looks something like this:

```php
    session_save_path('/home/expressptp/sessions');
    session_start();

    echo session_id();
    $_SESSION["test"] = "test";

    echo session_save_path(); //that prints good path
```

But the problem is that in folder `sessions` there are no sessions :(

I tried everything. I put 'sessions' folder in 'www', chmod 777, setting path with `realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`, etc.

If you have any ideas I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure nothing in your code has begun outputting ("echo" or html tags or text) to the browser before you try this code?

Many times session/header/cookie functions do not work as expected just because of that...

Also, many host providers do restrict these kind of configurations, have you checked if the session_save_path() function is disabled, or if OVH explicitly prohibits this configuration change?